# Scrapy CrawlSpider Attribute Not Found

Tags: python, scrapy

Using Scrapy 1.4.0 and a modified template I found online, I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'CrawlSpider'

The log doesn't appear to show anything else of interest.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class TechcrunchSpider(scrapy.CrawlSpider):
    #name of the spider
    name = 'stltoday'

    #list of allowed domains
    allowed_domains = ['http://graphics.stltoday.com/']

    #starting url for scraping
    start_urls = ['http://graphics.stltoday.com/apps/payrolls/salaries/2_1/']

    rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        allow=['/apps/payrolls/salaries/.*/$']),
        callback='parse',
        follow=True),
    ]

    #setting the location of the output csv file
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI' : 'tmp/stltoday.csv'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        #Remove XML namespaces
        response.selector.remove_namespaces()

        #Extract article information
        name = response.xpath("//th::text").extract()
        allother = response.xpath('//table[@class="table--department"]//td').extract()


        for item in zip(name,allother):
            scraped_info = {
                'name' : item[0],
                'allother' : item[1]
            }

            yield scraped_info
```

Comment: According to the [1.4.0 documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html), it's `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error implies that the module `scrapy` does not contain a `CrawlSpider` class. As stated in a comment, this is a result of a change in the documentation for scrapy. A quick fix should be to change

```
class TechcrunchSpider(scrapy.CrawlSpider):
```

to

```
class TechcrunchSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
```

which should resolve the issue!